# Upload file using httpwebrequest with same session

Tags: vb.net, session, file-upload, awesomium

i was inspired by Awesomium and im trying to use it as my client side app for my web application using vb.net . im trying to do an uploader module where our clinets can upload any files to our server . i used HttpWebRequest for uploading files which is working fine. but only problem is how to set the session created by Awesomium when i logged on to my web application to httpwebrequest . or is there any other way in awesomium itself to upload files to the server (ie php server ) .

Please apologies im not good in English.

below is the code im using for upload

```
    Dim filepath As String = Path  'Path to file on local machine 

    Dim url As String = "http://xxxxx.com/uploadscanfile.php"

    Dim boundary As String = IO.Path.GetRandomFileName
    ImageRandomName.Add(IO.Path.GetFileName(filepath))

    Dim header As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    header.AppendLine("--" & boundary)
    header.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file"";")
    header.AppendFormat("filename=""{0}""", IO.Path.GetFileName(filepath))
    header.AppendLine()
    header.AppendLine("Content-Type: application/octet-stream")
    header.AppendLine()

    Dim headerbytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header.ToString)
    Dim endboundarybytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vbNewLine & "--" & boundary & "--" & vbNewLine)

    Dim req As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
    req.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & boundary
    req.ContentLength = headerbytes.Length + New IO.FileInfo(filepath).Length + endboundarybytes.Length

    req.AllowAutoRedirect = True
    req.Timeout = -1
    req.KeepAlive = True
    req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = False
    req.Method = "POST"
    Dim s As IO.Stream = req.GetRequestStream
    s.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length)
    Dim filebytes() As Byte = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(filepath)
    s.Write(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length)
    s.Write(endboundarybytes, 0, endboundarybytes.Length)
    s.Close()
```

Comment: How do you track sessions in your app?  Using a cookie?  What is the name of the cookie?  What event triggers the upload?  How does the user select the filepath?

Comment: i included Awesomium in my project and set websession provider to WebSessionProvider1. im sorry im very basic to vb.net and i followded the instruction from awesomium docs and i hope all the session in awesomium is handled by websessionprovider1

Comment: You have two separate HTTP clients (browsers): the VB.NET HttpWebRequest and your Awesomium control.  You can upload files with the Awesomium control using an HTML form or with Javascript.  Why are you trying to upload files using VB.NET?

Comment: that is because im using a vb.net scanning module to scan from the local scanner and the files has to be uploaded to the server

Answer (score 0):

Typically, session info is stored in the cookies. So, you will first need to send the log in data (and receive a reply). Also, when receiving the reply, you need to set a `CookieContainer` in the `CookieContainer` property and you will reuse it later. Only then, you can send the form data and upload the file, but make sure to set the `CookieContainer` to the `CookieContainer` that has the log in cookies when uploading.

A good way to see all the request/responses that go through to/from the server when loging in, I suggest you use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) it is a very useful tool that monitors all the requests that you make. Note the headers, data that gets send and anything else that you may find useful.

More code:

Here is the part that logs you in: The post string that you send needs to contain the username and password. (and any other info that may be required).

```
    Dim CookieJar As New CookieContainer()    'The CookieContainer that will keep all the cookies. 
                                              'DO NOT CLEAR THIS BETWEEN REQUESTS! ONLY CLEAR TO "Log Out".

    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("<login URL goes here>")

    req.Method = "POST"
    req.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*"   'This may be a bit different in your case. Refer to what Fiddler will say.
    req.CookieContainer = CookieJar
    req.ContentLength = post_str.Length
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"    'Also, any useragent will do.
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1"
    req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.7,ru;q=0.3")
    req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
    req.Headers.Add("DNT", "1")       'Make sure to add all headers that you found using Fiddler!
    req.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache")

    Dim RequestWriter As New IO.StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream())
    RequestWriter.Write(post_str)      'Write the post string that contains the log in, password, etc.
    RequestWriter.Close()
    RequestWriter.Dispose()

    Dim ResponceReader As New IO.StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    Dim ResponceData As String = ResponceReader.ReadToEnd()
    ResponceReader.Close()
    ResponceReader.Dispose()

    req.GetResponse.Close()

    'In the long run, you can check the ResponceData to verify that the log in was successful.
```

Here is where the `CookieJar` gets used to sent a request:

```
    post_str = ""   'What needs to be sent goes in this variable.

    req = HttpWebRequest.Create("<page to send request to goes here>")

    req.Method = "POST"
    req.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*"   'May be different in your case
    req.CookieContainer = CookieJar    'Please note: this HAS to be the same CookieJar as you used to login.
    req.ContentLength = post_str.Length
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1"
    req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.7,ru;q=0.3")
    req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
    req.Headers.Add("DNT", "1")     'Add all headers here.
    req.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache")

    RequestWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream())
    RequestWriter.Write(post_str)
    RequestWriter.Close()
    RequestWriter.Dispose()

    ResponceReader = New IO.StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    ResponceData = ResponceReader.ReadToEnd()
    ResponceReader.Close()
    ResponceReader.Dispose()

    req.GetResponse.Close()

    'You may want to read the ResponceData.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: will you please explain me a bit more . im sorry im new to VB.Net and im under stress to complete this project

Comment: Ok, I made a project like this some time ago. I will try to find the code and post here.